# Python: User input irrespective of the version

Tags: python, string, input, version

I am making a script that takes a string input. However, I want this script to be independent of python 2.7 or python 3+.

For python 2.7 I write

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
```

For python 3+ I write

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
```

How can I write a single line of code that will be compatible with both the version ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backwards-compatible input calls in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868506/backwards-compatible-input-calls-in-python)

Comment: have you tried "try, exception" ?

Comment: Yea.. with exceptions I was prompting the user twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Python 2 and 3:
from builtins import input

name = input('What is your name? ')
assert isinstance(name, str)    # native str on Py2 and Py3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you could do this in a *single* line of code, but you could use the following:

```
try:
   input = raw_input
except NameError:
   pass
```

Now calling input will work as expected in both Python 2 and Python 3.